# Use require or import instead exec or the Function constructor

Tags: javascript, jestjs, requirejs, exec, web-worker

I'm working on a web worker polyfill for jest test environments. The web worker API takes in a file url and runs it in a new environment; I figured I could get most of the functionality by relying on the `Function` constructor.

Currently the code:

- takes a filepath
- loads the file as a string
- calls `Function` on the file outputs to create a function
- returns an object with a `postMessage` function that calls the dynamically created function above

(This is all based on the jsdom-worker package, here: https://github.com/developit/jsdom-worker)

This works for smallish test cases, but it fails when the code I'm passing in has `require(foo)` or `import 'foo'` in it. This fails regardless of whether I have jest configured to run a module or not; the issue is that the `Function` constructor only runs CommonJS.

Is there a way to get either `require` or `import` working inside the `Function` constructor (or equivalently, in `exec`)?